# How to test overloaded method using spock "where" table

Tags: groovy, null, spock

I want to test passing `null` to these overloaded methods:

```
public static Object someMethod(String n) { /* some impl */ }
public static Object someMethod(Integer n) { /* some impl */ }
```

I tried:

```
def "test someMethod"() {
    expect:
    someMethod(input) == expected
    where:
    input           | expected
    null as String  | someValue
    null as Integer | someValue
}
```

But I get the error:

```
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method com.foo.MyClass#someMethod.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null] due to overlapping prototypes between:  
    [class java.lang.String]  
    [class java.lang.Integer]
```

How can I test these using one spock method with the input nulls in a `where` block (with other values)?

Comment: Don't know if it works. In where section try to define closure: `{ someMethod(null as String) } | someValue` and in expect section `input()==expected`

Comment: I was trying to reproduce your problem with Spock 1.3 and Groovy 2.5.8, but couldn't. I had another Spock problem instead, see [here](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/589#issuecomment-539323700). You must be using other versions of Spock and/or Groovy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type cast are not carried over and cannot be carried over by Spock in this case.
But you can use a `PojoWrapper` manually, which is how Groovy internally represents a type-casted `null`:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.wrappers.PojoWrapper

def "test someMethod"() {
    expect:
    someMethod(input) == expected
    where:
    input                          | expected
    new PojoWrapper(null, String)  | someValue
    new PojoWrapper(null, Integer) | someValue
}
```

One important note though, the first set of inputs must contain wrappers, or Groovy optimizes the `someMethod` call in a way that does not unwrap the parameters.

So this will work:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.wrappers.PojoWrapper

def "test someMethod"() {
    expect:
    someMethod(input) == expected
    where:
    input                          | expected
    new PojoWrapper(null, Integer) | someValue
    0                              | someValue
}
```

while this will not work but throw a `ClassCastException`:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.wrappers.PojoWrapper

def "test someMethod"() {
    expect:
    someMethod(input) == expected
    where:
    input                          | expected
    0                              | someValue
    new PojoWrapper(null, Integer) | someValue
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to reproduce your problem with Spock 1.3 and Groovy 2.5.8, but couldn't. I had another Spock problem instead, see [here](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/589#issuecomment-539323700). You must be using other versions of Spock and/or Groovy.

Anyway, one workaround for the Spock bug I was just linking to is to not call the method with the null parameter from a `then:` or `expect:` block but from `when:` and do the comparison later in the `then:` block. See also my code example there.

In addition to that, you need to split your feature method into two methods, one for each type of `null` object you want to test.

**Java class under test:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q58279620;

public class ClassUnderTest {
  public static Object someMethod(String n) {
    return n == null ? "nothing" : "something";
  }

  public static Object someMethod(Integer n) {
    return n == null ? -999 : 11;
  }
}
```

**Spock test workaround:**

```
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q58279620


import spock.lang.Specification
import spock.lang.Unroll

class PassingNullToOverloadedMethodTest extends Specification {
  @Unroll
  def "someMethod('#input') returns #expected"() {
    when:
    def result = ClassUnderTest.someMethod(input as String)

    then:
    result == expected

    where:
    input | expected
    "foo" | "something"
    ""    | "something"
    null  | "nothing"
  }

  @Unroll
  def "someMethod(#input) returns #expected"() {
    when:
    def result = ClassUnderTest.someMethod(input as Integer)

    then:
    result == expected

    where:
    input | expected
    0     | 11
    123   | 11
    null  | -999
  }
}
```

Comment: This is correct way: have isolated tests. Even overloaded methods represent different units under testing.

Comment: A workaround doesn’t actually answer the question; it provides a workaround to the problem. Your “workaround” actually sidesteps the problem entirely, making it not relevant to the core issue of how to target a specific overloading given mixed types in a where block. Quoting from the question: *How can I test these using **one** spock method*. If it can be proven that my question does not have a solution, I would accept a workaround, but IIRC I solved it myself - I’ll check my code base tomorrow for commits around October to try to find what I did and post it as an answer if I find it.

Comment: And how would like that to be proven? Maybe via mathematical proof? That the Spock manual doesn't tell you how to do it, there is no relevant sample code to be found on the entire internet and an experienced Spock user says he knows no other way is not enough, obviously. You should concentrate on writing good tests in a clean way, which is what I am offering by using two feature methods in order to test two distinct object methods. Why do you insist in a contrived solution?